# I need to Copy OEM Ubuntu hardive

Tags: hardware, oem

I am going to sell computers with Ubuntu OS and want to per install software. I am using the OEM ubuntu software but can`t figure out how to copy it to a another hardive. I need a master copy that i  can easily install on a computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use cloning software like

- [clonezilla](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clonezilla)
- [partclone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partclone)
- or the *older* [partimage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partimage)

to make your master copy, and deploy it latter on on other PC/HDD.

I can't recommend one as I haven't use any of them, yet.